# PHP session in url

Tags: php, session

I want to append a url, and right now I have this:

```
test.php?id=Netherlands
```

the end result should be something like this (please correct me if this is the wrong way)

```
   test.php?id=Netherlands&stats=semifinals
```

The problem right now is that I want to append a link on the `test.php?id=Netherlands` url, and Netherlands can be like any other id, like Belgium, France etc...

So, I need to retrieve session['id'] that I created from the other link I clicked on.

My problem now is that when I put

```
<li> <a href="test.php?id="<?php echo$_SESSION['id'];?>>Round of 16</a></li>
```

and click on it, it shows nothing, like this: `test.php?id=`

when I echo `<?php echo$_SESSION['id'];?` it does show, so the session works.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to make sure, when you echo your session id, does it actually print this: Netherlands&stats=semifinals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<li> <a href="test.php?id="<?php echo$_SESSION['id'];?>>Round of 16</a></li>
```

By:

```
<li> <a href="test.php?id=<?php echo$_SESSION['id'];?>">Round of 16</a></li>
```

You were closing the href right after the = of the id

Comment: Don't, we all did that mistake at least once :)

Comment: Will put you as answer in 5 minutes because of timer ;').

btw: is the method to create a 2nd session just putting &php?stats=semifinals correct?

Comment: Yes but beware, because there is a difference between SESSION and GET. Unless your code moves everything from GET or REQUEST to your session, passing a var with ?var=value does not interact with the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li> <a href="test.php?id="<?php echo$_SESSION['id'];?>>Round of 16</a></li>
```

Remove " and put a space between echo and your variable:

```
 <li><a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">Round of 16</a></li>
```